# resolve a promise after forEach with conditional inner promises are finished

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following promise that goes across an array. Based on value of an array item, another call might be made. If not, nothing. it resolves an object at last. But the problem is now it resolves early. If a car's state is already known, the numbers returned fine. If it needs to be detected on the fly, it don't wait for the state to be determined:

```
getAggregatedData(obj: StorageUnit): Promise<any> {
    let stat = {
      inStoreCars: 0,
      atWorkCars: 0
    };

    const vm: any = this;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      obj.carsList.forEach(car => {

          if (car.inStore) {
            stat.inStoreCars++;
          } else if (car.atWork) {
            stat.atWorkCars++;
          }
          // unknown state. so check its state
          else {


                vm.carStateService
                  .getState(car)
                  .then(value => {
                   if (value == 1){
                       stat.inStoreCars++;
                   }else{
                       stat.atWorkCars++;
                   }
                  });


          }

      });
      resolve(stat) // returning too early before getState() resolves
    });
  }
```

then I am calling it normally with

```
    getAggregatedData(car).then(stat=>{
       console.log(stat)
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of need lil more info, but at ones. Having a function that makes some asynchronous stuff n sync, is an anti pattern, because how the event loop works. Why do you even need the promise for ? If you are using typescript, why not async await. Another antipattern creating and executing the promise on same place

Comment: i did try the function without Promise and it had no change so thought I would make it a promise and wait for it to return value through a resolve(). It is called from another method that have a bunch of stuff related to StorageUnit objects and I wanted a clear way to get stat of each storage Unit processed. Would async/await make a difference? If is it not too much to ask, can you share with me a correct pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with .forEach(), you will have to use the traditional for loop instead. There is a working example below (I copied from your sample code best I could).

```
function test() {
        let stat = {
            inStoreCars: 0,
            atWorkCars: 0,
        }
        const carsList = [1, 0, 1, 0];
        return new Promise<any>(async (resolve) => {
            for (let i in carsList) {
                const car = carsList[i];
                stat = await new Promise<any>((res) => {
                    setTimeout(() => res(car), 5000);
                })
                    .then(value => {
                        console.log("then");
                        if (value == 1) {
                            stat.inStoreCars++;
                            return stat;
                        } else {
                            stat.atWorkCars++;
                            return stat;
                        }
                    });
            }
            resolve(stat);
        });
    }
    test().then((val) => alert(JSON.stringify(val)));
```

I changed the returned promise to use an async function and added a return to getState().then() so I could await the change. You should be able to do the same thing if you do `state = await vm.carStateService.getState(...)`

Comment: Thanks. It has given me a rough idea but looks like I have to call the inner promise even when a car's state is already known, right? I was hoping to call the inner promise only if i don't know the state of the car. Thanks still; will look for the way